# CSS styles are not being applied

Tags: html, css

I am working on a small web project which was working perfectly fine for some time but suddenly some CSS styles are not being applied anymore.

I have applied styles through a class in HTML.

When I write the same styles inline they are working fine but when applied through a class in HTML, they aren't working.

My question is, why are they working inline but not when I put them in a class and attach a CSS file?

Comment: did you attach the file correctly. can you share your HTML code where you linked??

Comment: can u pls share your html code where u linked ur css file and as well as the folder structure ?

Comment: Please share your HTML along with your CSS so you can get better answers.

Comment: Hi, please read the article of SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

If they are working inline but not when the file is linked I would guess that the link to the css file might have a typo.  I had a similar problem earlier and turns out I was linking index.css instead of styles/index.css since I had put the css into its own folder.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the path of your css file wherever you linked it.

If its not a typo then simply press **Ctrl+F5** in chrome (Windows).

Many times when your css file is large so your browser stores it in cache and hence not every time it renders your css file when updated in editor and reloaded the site.

To rectify this simply press Ctrl+F5.

This will clear the browser cache for that tab(that website) and reload the page forcing the browser to render the updated css.

EDIT: For Mac if you are using safari, the shortcut is Command+Alt+E

In Mac if you are using Chrome, Ctrl+F5 will not work, so refer to this site: https://clear-my-cache.com/en/apple-mac-os/google-chrome.html